# SignalR binding error on polymorphic data

Tags: asp.net-core, polymorphism, signalr

I am encountering following exception while using [TypedSignalR](https://github.com/nenoNaninu/TypedSignalR.Client) library, but I am pretty sure it is not strictly related:

Client side exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubException: Failed to invoke 'PushEvent' due to an error on the server. InvalidDataException: Error binding arguments. Make sure that the types of the provided values match the types of the hub method being invoked.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.InvokeCoreAsyncCore(String methodName, Type returnType, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.InvokeCoreAsync(String methodName, Type returnType, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnectionExtensions.InvokeCoreAsync[TResult](HubConnection hubConnection, String methodName, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at ....'

Server side exception:

> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Error binding arguments. Make sure
> that the types of the provided values match the types of the hub
> method being invoked.  ---> System.NotSupportedException:
> Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type
> '....Abstraction.IEvent'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |
> BytePositionInLine: 8.  ---> System.NotSupportedException:
> Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type
> '.....Abstraction.IEvent'.
> ...
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.ParseMessage(ReadOnlySequence`1
> input, IInvocationBinder binder)

These are the two sides of the call:
[image: screenhot]

I know what the message means.

- I am using `System.Text.Json`
- The server is .net 7, the client is .net 8
- **IEvent is polymorphic** and it is set up according to what is needed to work with *System.Text.Json* (`[JsonPolymorphic]` and `[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Common.SystemEvent), "SE")]`, and so on...).
- I have a common `JsonSerializerOptions` instance that is used in all other places both for serializing and deserializing.
- Have registered it for http both on the client and the server: `builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => Serialization.JsonSerializerOptions.Adapt(options.SerializerOptions));`
- On the server I have explicitly set up JsonProtocol to use it:
  `builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options =>  Serialization.JsonSerializerOptions.Adapt(options.PayloadSerializerOptions) );`
- Likewise on the client:
   `connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().AddJsonProtocol(options => Serialization.JsonSerializerOptions.Adapt(options.PayloadSerializerOptions))`
- In a linqpad sketch there is no issue deserializing

But still does not work. I also know that System.Text.Json deserializer **can** deserialize to interface if it is polymorphic and the discriminator is present. I made a linqpad sketch using the actual library with the actual types involved, and it has no issues at all (the methods used simply wrap the usage of the common options):

[image: test]

**[Update]**
As a workaround, I have added an method to handle it directly as string, and it also works. How come, that the same library can handle the same serialized data in one place and can't in an other....

[image: workaround]

**[Update 2]**
Even stranger: I have a sibling call, that sends multiple instances at a time. And that is working as expected:
[image: sending multiple]

**[Update 3: 23-12-21]**
Neither is it an issue in any property is of a *polymorphic interface* type. I have looked on the SignalR code, and it seems that only the parameters binder has problems with that. I have not found yet the exact spot where this could be fixed...

Here is a minimal reproducible example (LinqPad 8):

```
async Task Main()
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateSlimBuilder();
    builder.Services.AddSignalR(o => o.EnableDetailedErrors = true);
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    app.Urls.Add("http://localhost:3000");
    
    app.MapHub<EmptyHub>("/hub");

    var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://localhost:3000/hub")
                .Build();
                    
    await app.StartAsync();
    
    await connection.StartAsync();

    try
    {
        III x1 = new C1 { A = 100 };
        III x2 = new C2 { B = 100 };
        
        await connection.InvokeAsync(nameof(EmptyHub.HubMethod3), new W(x1)); // ok
        await connection.InvokeAsync(nameof(EmptyHub.HubMethod3), new W(x2)); // ok
        await connection.InvokeAsync(nameof(EmptyHub.HubMethod2), new[] { x1, x2 }); // ok
        await connection.InvokeAsync(nameof(EmptyHub.HubMethodThatWillFail), x1); // will fail
        
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        app.Logger.LogError(ex, "Problem");
    }
    finally
    {
        await app.StopAsync();
    }
}

public class EmptyHub(ILogger<EmptyHub> logger) : Hub
{
    public void HubMethodThatWillFail(III message) 
    {
        logger.LogInformation(message.GetType().Name);
    }
    
    public void HubMethod2(IEnumerable<III> message)
    {
        logger.LogInformation(string.Join(", ", message.Select(x => x.GetType().Name)));
    }

    public void HubMethod3(W message)
    {
        logger.LogInformation(message.Data.GetType().Name);
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Connected: {id}", Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}

public record W(III Data);

[JsonPolymorphic()]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(C1), nameof(C1))]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(C2), nameof(C2))]
public interface III
{
}

public class C1 : III
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}

public class C2 : III
{
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

1. How can I debug the actual message being sent/received? I am using serilog, but `"Serilog:MinimumLevel:Override:Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Verbose"` seems not to be enough
2. Am I missing something here?